# What is this type of plot called?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology

Often times in simulation studies, we need to display the various settings in a coherent, well-organized way. I came about such a plot

[image]

This plot displays 5 characteristics which were varied for a total of $3 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 2 = 72$ total simulation scenarios comparing 4 methods. What is the name for this plot?

Comment: Without knowing what the horizontal axis represents or what the piecewise constant graphs are intended to mean, it's a little difficult to tell.